# Trying to overwrite method, receive "uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to ... must be an instance of ..."

Tags: magento2

Here's the contents of Brock/Deleter/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php (with the actual methods removed, to be short enough to include):

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Brock\Deleter\Model\Product\Type;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Config;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\ReadHandler as GalleryReadHandler;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Collection\SalableProcessor;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool;

/**
 * Configurable product type implementation
 *
 * This type builds in product attributes and existing simple products
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.TooManyFields)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveClassComplexity)
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 * @api
 * @since 100.0.2
 */
class Configurable extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType
{
    /**
     * Product type code
     */
    const TYPE_CODE = 'configurable';

    /**
     * Cache key for Used Product Attribute Ids
     *
     * @var string
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    protected $usedProductAttributeIds = '_cache_instance_used_product_attribute_ids';

    /**
     * Cache key for Used Product Attributes
     *
     * @var string
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    protected $usedProductAttributes = '_cache_instance_used_product_attributes';

    /**
     * Cache key for Used Attributes
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_usedAttributes = '_cache_instance_used_attributes';

    /**
     * Cache key for configurable attributes
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_configurableAttributes = '_cache_instance_configurable_attributes';

    /**
     * Cache key for Used product ids
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_usedProductIds = '_cache_instance_product_ids';

    /**
     * Cache key for used products
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_usedProducts = '_cache_instance_products';

    /**
     * Cache key for salable used products
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $usedSalableProducts = '_cache_instance_salable_products';

    /**
     * Product is composite
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_isComposite = true;

    /**
     * Product is configurable
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_canConfigure = true;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $_scopeConfig;

    /**
     * Catalog product type configurable
     *
     * @var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable
     */
    protected $_catalogProductTypeConfigurable;

    /**
     * Attribute collection factory
     *
     * @var
     * \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_attributeCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Product collection factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Configurable attribute factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\AttributeFactory
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    protected $configurableAttributeFactory;

    /**
     * Eav attribute factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\AttributeFactory
     */
    protected $_eavAttributeFactory;

    /**
     * Type configurable factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\ConfigurableFactory
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    protected $typeConfigurableFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttribute\JoinProcessorInterface
     */
    protected $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface
     */
    private $cache;

    /**
     * @var MetadataPool
     */
    private $metadataPool;

    /**
     * @var GalleryReadHandler
     */
    private $productGalleryReadHandler;

    /**
     * @var Config
     */
    private $catalogConfig;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    private $customerSession;

    /**
     * Product factory
     *
     * @var ProductInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $productFactory;

    /**
     * Collection salable processor
     *
     * @var SalableProcessor
     */
    private $salableProcessor;

    /**
     * @codingStandardsIgnoreStart/End
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $catalogProductOption
     * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type $catalogProductType
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager
     * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $fileStorageDb
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\ConfigurableFactory $typeConfigurableFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\AttributeFactory $eavAttributeFactory
     * @param \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\AttributeFactory $configurableAttributeFactory
     * @param \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute\CollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable $catalogProductTypeConfigurable
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttribute\JoinProcessorInterface $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serializer
     * @param ProductInterfaceFactory $productFactory
     * @param SalableProcessor $salableProcessor
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Option $catalogProductOption,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type $catalogProductType,
        \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database $fileStorageDb,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\ConfigurableFactory $typeConfigurableFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\AttributeFactory $eavAttributeFactory,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable\AttributeFactory $configurableAttributeFactory,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable\Attribute\CollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable $catalogProductTypeConfigurable,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\ExtensionAttribute\JoinProcessorInterface $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor,
        \Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface $cache = null,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serializer = null,
        ProductInterfaceFactory $productFactory = null,
        SalableProcessor $salableProcessor = null
    ) {
        $this->typeConfigurableFactory = $typeConfigurableFactory;
        $this->_eavAttributeFactory = $eavAttributeFactory;
        $this->configurableAttributeFactory = $configurableAttributeFactory;
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_attributeCollectionFactory = $attributeCollectionFactory;
        $this->_catalogProductTypeConfigurable = $catalogProductTypeConfigurable;
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->extensionAttributesJoinProcessor = $extensionAttributesJoinProcessor;
        $this->cache = $cache;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(ProductInterfaceFactory::class);
        $this->salableProcessor = $salableProcessor ?: ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SalableProcessor::class);
        parent::__construct(
            $catalogProductOption,
            $eavConfig,
            $catalogProductType,
            $eventManager,
            $fileStorageDb,
            $filesystem,
            $coreRegistry,
            $logger,
            $productRepository,
            $serializer
        );
    }

}
```

Returns error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Builder\Plugin::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable, instance of Brock\Deleter\Model\Product\Type\Configurable given, called in /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 111 and defined in /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Builder/Plugin.php:31 Stack trace: #0 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Builder\Plugin->__construct(Object(Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory), Object(Brock\Deleter\Model\Product\Type\Configurable)) #1 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(66): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Configu...', Array) #2 /srv/public_html/vendor/mage in /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Builder/Plugin.php on line 31
```

Have cleared generation folder, etc.

Also, I just need to modify one method, but get a different error unless I copy over all of the original methods.

Any thoughts would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding the whole class is not recommended. Did you try to use plugin? Which method you want to change and how?

If you need to override the whole class it will be better to just extend  `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable`
and change preference. See this tutorial: https://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/

Comment: I used preference, in di.xml

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable" type="Brock\Deleter\Model\Product\Type\Configurable" />
</config>`

Comment: Good, but I think you need to extend `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable` not the `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType`

Comment: Which method you want to override?

Comment: Ha! That's it. Gotcha.

Comment: Your welcome ;)